# How to connect a Django rest framework into android app in testing environment?

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, retrofit, retrofit2

I have built a django website for blog posts, and i have built rest APIs for it also so i can use it into my android app, but that website is working in my local host, now i have tried to connect it with an android app using retrofit and tried to make a simple call from the android app but it doesn't work, i just need the very basic steps to connect that local host to my android app and i will take care of retrofit calls and other coding stuff.

I have already tried to create retrofit client passing BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000" but it doesn't work too

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
private static RetrofitClient instance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

private RetrofitClient(){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Api getApi(){
    return retrofit.create(Api.class);
}
```

When making a simple call it the onFailure method triggers

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 would be the local machine-  the phone (or emulator) itself.  That's the wrong address.  If its an emulator and your server is on the PC, use 10.0.2.2.  Otherwise, use the actual address (make sure its either  public IP or they're on the same network).

Answer (score 0):

Just simply run your Django server with the command:

```
Python manage.py runserver Your-machine-IP:8000
```

You will get an error about allowed IPs; just add you Local IP to the said file.